# python selenium site spider from page option list

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, html-select

I'm using `Python2.7` and `Selenium` and am trying to use a select box's option list for the basis of my site spider functionality, lets get right to the code:

```
 select = self.br.find_element_by_name( field )  #get the select element            
 options = select.find_elements_by_tag_name("option") #get all the options into a list

 for option in options: #iterate over the options
     print "starting loop on option %s" % option.text

     #now get the option with the value that is currently being iterated over and select it from the original select box source
     self.br.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='%s']/option[@value='%s']" % ( field, option.get_attribute("value") ) ).click() #the click takes you to a new page

     source = self.br.page_source #get the new page source

     #now check to see if some required data is on the navigated page, and print some stuff if so
     if "There is no summary data available." not in source:
          print "the new page is good! Here are the original args: ", option.text, option.get_attribute("value") 
     #time to go back to the main page and click the next option element
     self.br.back()
     print "went backwards" #for debugging
```

So, everything works until the second iteration after the `self.br.back()` and the loop starts again.  I get an extremely long Selenium error stating:

```
 selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: u'Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up' ; Stacktrace: 
at fxdriver.cache.getElementAt (resource://fxdriver/modules/web_element_cache.js:7643)
at Utils.getElementAt (file:///tmp/tmpm_ciQJ/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:7232)
at WebElement.getElementAttribute (file:///tmp/tmpm_ciQJ/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10335)
at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///tmp/tmpm_ciQJ/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10840)
at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///tmp/tmpm_ciQJ/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10845)
at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///tmp/tmpm_ciQJ/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10787)
```

Clearly the error says the element may no longer exist, but how would that be possible since I'm just iterating over a list of objects that was retrieved during a previous page session...

In any case, how should I go about doing this? Maybe the way I'm trying isn't the best way...

Comment: I believe your problem is here:  option.get_attribute("value") - It's part of the find elements options.  Once you leave the page, then return, it's trying to address something that is on the previous instance of your starting page.

Comment: @Richard it seems you are right, I commented out the `if` statement and then it failed on the print statement with `option.text`.  But how then should I be referencing the option info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely familiar with python, so you may need to rework this slightly.  I think this will at the very least get you started.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select, WebDriverWait

select = self.br.find_element_by_name( field )  #get the select element            
options = select.find_elements_by_tag_name("option") #get all the options into a list

optionsList = []

for option in options: #iterate over the options, place attribute value in list
    optionsList.append(option.get_attribute("value"))

for optionValue in optionsList:
    print "starting loop on option %s" % optionValue

    select = Select(self.br.find_element_by_name( field ))
    select.select_by_value(optionValue)

    source = self.br.page_source #get the new page source

    #now check to see if some required data is on the navigated page, and print some stuff if so
    if "There is no summary data available." not in source:
         print "the new page is good! Here are the original args: ", optionValue
    #time to go back to the main page and click the next option element
    self.br.back()
    print "went backwards" #for debugging
```

The idea here is to build a list of the option values in the first for loop, then iterate over those option values to navigate to the second page in the second for loop.  Use the python Select library to select those option values.  I put in a line to get a new reference to the dropdown each time through the second for loop.

I hope this was helpful

Comment: haha, that is exactly what I did while I was waiting for your answer! Of course, a few changes would be that you can't call `option.text` or the `option.get_attribute...` in the print expression later in the loop either

Comment: Ah, you're right.  I missed that while I was working on my answer.  I made a couple of edits to fix it up.  Thanks for accepting my answer.